Prove that $\lim_{q\to 1} \frac{ (tq;q)_{\infty} }{ (tq^y;q)_{\infty} }=(1-t)^{y-1}$
I want to show that \begin{equation}
\lim_{q\to 1^{-}}\frac{(1-tq)(1-tq^2)\ldots }{(1-tq^y)(1-tq^{y+1})\ldots}=(1-t)^{y-1}\end{equation}
For the case where $y$ is a natural number is evident, I could just telescope the product
I tried to take log both sides and expand using Taylor series, but that didn't work as I cannot switch limits.
I can let $f_q(t,y)=\frac{(1-tq)(1-tq^2)\ldots }{(1-tq^y)(1-tq^{y+1})\ldots}$ and we have the functional formula $$f_1(t,y)=(1-t)f_1(t,y-1)$$
Which depicts the limit quite well, but regardless I am still unable to prove the limit.
Any help is appreciated

See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453131/q-series-identities?noredirect=1
